# Issue with string and pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers

Can somebody tell me why this program does not work?

```
int main()
{
    char *num = 'h';
    printf("%c", num);
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is:

`1>c:\users\\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sssdsdsds\sssdsdsds\sssdsdsds.cpp(4): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'char' to 'char *'`

But if I write the code like that:

```
int main()
{
    char num = 'h';
    printf("%c", num);
    return 0;
}
```

it's working.

Comment: Why would you *expect* it to work? What do you think the '*' means, and why do you think putting it there doesn't matter?

Answer (score 5):

```
char *num = 'h';
```

Here, the letter `'h'` is a `char`, which you are trying to assign to a `char*`. The two types are not the same, so you get the problem that you see above.

This would work:

```
char *num = "h";
```

The difference is that here you're using double-quotes (`"`), which creates a `char*`.

This would also work:

```
char letter = 'h';
char* ptrToLetter = &letter;
```

You should read up on pointers in C to understand exactly what these different constructions do.

Answer (score 2):

`char *` is a pointer to a char, not the same thing than a single `char`.

If you have `char *`, then you must initialize it with `"`, not with `'`.

And also, for the formatting representation in `printf()`:

- the `%s` is used for `char *`
- the `%c` is only for `char`.

Answer (score 0):

In thefirst case you declared num as a pointer to a char.  In the second case, you declare it as a char.  In each case, you assign a char to the variable.  You can't assign a char to a pointer to a char, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

'h' = Char
"h" = Null terminated String

```
int main()
{
    char *num = "h";
    printf("%s", num);   // <= here change c to s if you want to print out string
    return 0;
}
```

this will work

Answer (score 0):

As somebody just said, when you write

```
char *num = 'h'
```

The compiler gives you an error because you're trying to give to a pointer a value. Pointers, you know, are just variables that store only the memory address of another variable you defined before. However, you can access to a variable's memory address with the operator:

```
&
```

And a variable's pointer should be coerent in type with the element pointed. 
For example, here is how should you define correctly a ptr:

```
int value = 5;

//defining a Ptr to value

int *ptr_value = &value;

//by now, ptr_value stores value's address
```

Anyway, you should study somewhere how this all works and how can ptrs be implemented, if you have other problems try a more specific question :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `char *h`, you are declaring a pointer to a `char` variable. This pointer keeps the address of the variable it points to.

In simple words, as you simply declare a char variable as `char num='h'`, then the variable `num`  will hold the value `h` and so if you print it using `printf("%c",num)`, you will get the output as `h`.

But, if you declare a variable as a pointer, as `char *num`, then it cannot actually hold any character value. I can hold only the address of some character variable.

For example look at the code below

```
void main()
{
    char a='h';
    char *b;
    b=&a;
    printf("%c",a);
    printf("%c",b);
    printf("%u",b);
}
```

here , we have one char variable `a` and one char pointer `b`. Now the variable `a` may be located somewhere in memory that we do not know. `a` holds the value `h` and `&a` means `address of a in memory` The statement `b=&a` will assign the memory address of `a` to `b`. Since `b` is declared as a pointer, It can hold the address.

The statenment `printf("%c",b)` will print out garbage values.

The statement `printf("%u",b)` will print the address of variable `a` in memory.

so there's difference between `char num` and `char *num`. You must first read about pointers. They are different from normal variables and must be used very carefully.